# Alternative to suphp?

Tags: php, debian

After a very long time since I installed `suphp` 5.* into my server, today I wanted to upgrade to php7.4 or php7.3, but I've found out that `suphp` is no longer maintained! And my knowledge is outdated with php versions. I've tried to find an alternative all I can see there is `php-fpm` .

I have 2 VPSs, centos 7 and Debian 10. is it possible to keep using suphp but a higher version? Or should I switch to the alternative?

Comment: if suphp is unmaintained , what i can use as alternative? the websites r using 755 and 644 suphp files and folders permissions , i need to keep it like this

Comment: As you've already found, `suphp` was terminated as a project in May 2013 and [removed from Debian repositories in February 2014](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=738133). Ubuntu then removed `libapache2-mod-suphp` in version 15.10. What you will need to use instead is [the `apache2-suexec` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&keywords=apache2-suexec) ... assuming you replace the CentOS and Debian boxes with Ubuntu Server. Be advised that this will require some code changes to your PHP code, as `suexec` is not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: hmmm , is it possible to do it without effecting the php websites on the server , i mean just upgrade the suphp 5 to php7.4 fpm?

Comment: Highly doubt it. When in doubt, though, create a VM with the modern software stack and try your website code on there. All it’ll cost you is time.

Answer (score 0):

Suphp is intrinsically incompatible with the performance and scalability functionality of modern PHP. There are some **very** obscure edge cases where there has been a benefit to using it. You didn't tell us why you *require* its functionality - so you're not going to get an answer which addresses your use-case.

Using php-fpm with the ondemand process management, then you only have the additional overhead of defining a pool for each uid (and most of the content is template / creation can be scripted). Do bear in mind that you will need to override the default config for session storage and need to take into consideration the debian/ubuntu model for session expiry (but if you are already using suphp with sessions, then you already know that).

Generally however, its a better idea to use containerization as a means of isolation, and if you need to privilege elevation than move that functionality outside your website and access it via sudo + process control (pexec, shell_exec, popen etc).